# String search and replace program implementation in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am making a C program to find a string and replace it with a desired string.
Suppose my source string is `Welcome bob. How are you bob?`, my program will replace each instances of `bob` with `job`. Here pattern string is `bob` and the replace string is `job`.

I use Code::Blocks as my IDE. Whenever I give my program a source string like `bit bit bi b` my program will replace all instances of `bit` to desired string, say `mit`, but add some strange characters to the last of output string. For `bit bit bi b` source string my final string comes out to be `mit mit bi bX▒`.

It can be seen that some strange characters are added to last of the string. This thing only happens when *last string of my source string is sub-string of the pattern string*. In other cases like when the source string is `welcome bob job`, when the *last string of my source string is not the sub-string of the pattern string* the program works correctly.

Why this is happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main() {
    int i = 0, j = 0, t = 0, k = 0, m = 0;
    char s[50], p[50], r[50], f[50];
    gets(s);  //source string
    gets(p);  //pattern string
    gets(r);  //replace string
    while (s[i] != '\0') {
        if (s[m++] == p[j++]) {
            if (p[j] == '\0') {
                for (k = 0; r[k] != '\0'; k++, t++)
                    f[t] = r[k];
                i = i + strlen(p);
                j = 0;
            }
        } else {
            f[t++] = s[i++];
            j = 0;
            m = i;
        }
    }
    puts(f);
}
```

I just want to know why the output is having unwanted or strange characters.

Comment: Find a new book, this is obsolete. For instance, `main()` is not a valid signature for `main()` and `gets()` is deprecated and should never be used, it's actually no longer part of the standard library.

Comment: `gets`: just don't use it

Comment: At the end of the string, set the NUL character(`'\0'` aka `0`) as the terminator.

Comment: I suggest you learn how to use your debugger. This kind of simple program is a perfect occasion for doing so. The debugger allows you to execute your program line by line and lets you inspect the state of all variables.

Comment: I also suggest using more explicit variable names than just `s`, `p`, `r` and `f`, e.g. `source`, `pattern`, `replacement`, `destination` etc.

Comment: And please don't ask: _why doses it work if the last string of my source string is not a sub-string of the pattern string_. It only _seems_ to work. You are not terminating your destination string (`f`) with a `NUL` character, therefore you have an indeterminate value after the last valid character of `f` and using `puts` will result in _undefined behaviour_ (google that term). Actually `puts` will print the valid characters of `f` followed by whatever junk characters comes after that, until a `NUL` character is encountered. The program may even crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you get spurious characters at the end of the output is you do not set the null terminator at the end of the `f` array.  Insert `f[t] = '\0';` before the `puts(f);`.

Your code has other problems:

- The signature for `main` without arguments is `int main(void)`
- You should not use `gets()`, this function is unsafe and has been remove from the latest version of the C Standard. Use `scanf()` or `fgets()` and remove the trailing newline.
- You do not check if the output exceeds the size of the `f` array, which can happen if the replacement string is longer than the pattern string.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    int i, j, m;
    char s[100], p[100], r[100];

    if (fgets(s, sizeof s, stdin)     // source string
    &&  fgets(p, sizeof p, stdin)     // pattern string
    &&  fgets(r, sizeof r, stdin)) {  // replace string
        s[strcspn(s, "\n")] = '\0';   // strip newline if any
        p[strcspn(p, "\n")] = '\0';   // strip newline if any
        r[strcspn(r, "\n")] = '\0';   // strip newline if any
        i = j = m = 0;
        while (s[i] != '\0') {
            if (s[m++] == p[j++]) {
                if (p[j] == '\0') {
                    fputs(r, stdout);
                    i = m;
                    j = 0;
                }
            } else {
                putchar(s[i++]);
                j = 0;
                m = i;
            }
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You said that I should terminate the string with null but even if I don't do as evident from the program, the program was working correctly in the other case. Can you explain why?

Comment: the destination array was not explicitly null terminated, its contents beyond the end of the part that was copied is uninitialized. It is possible that there was a `'\0'` there in some tests and not in others, depending on the length or other factors.

Answer (score -1):

Search and replace. needle and replace can be any size valid strings. If buff is null result will be stored in the haystack, if not it will be stored in the buff. If strlen(needle) == 0 the original string is returned.

You need to provide large enough buffer. It can be haystack or buff

```
char *strreplace(char *haystack, const char *needle, const char *replace, char *buff)
{
    int length = strlen(haystack);
    int needlelength = strlen(needle);
    int replacelength = strlen(replace);
    char *ptr = buff;
    char *start, *source, *dest;

    if (buff == NULL)
    {
        ptr = malloc((length + 1) * sizeof(char));
        source = ptr;
        dest = haystack;
    }
    else
    {
        source = haystack;
        dest = buff;
    }

    if (ptr != NULL)
    {
        if (buff == NULL) strcpy(ptr, haystack);
        else
        {
           if (!length) 
            {
                *buff = 0;
            }
        }
        while (needlelength && *source)
        {
            size_t chunklen;
            char *result;

            start = source;
            if ((result = strstr(source, needle)) == NULL)
            {
                strcpy(dest, source);
                break;
            }
            chunklen = result - start;
            strncpy(dest, start, chunklen);
            dest += chunklen;
            strcpy(dest, replace);
            dest += replacelength;
            source = result;
            source += needlelength;
        }
        if (buff == NULL)
        {
            free(ptr);
            ptr = haystack;
        }
        else
        {
            ptr = buff;
        }
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

Comment: Hey DV-ter Comment?